# How to implement TLS/SSL for python Bottle using Gevent

Tags: python, web-services, ssl, bottle, gevent

- Hi, I am using **Bottle** python module for my web server.
- I use `monkey.patch_all()` function from **gevent** to implement
  concurrency.
- My server is working perfectly.
- But now i need to implement TLS/SSL for my web server.

I found many ways of implementing it using **CherryPy** module.

> But I need to implement it without using CherryPy or any other module.

Is there any way to add TLS by using Bottle and Gevent?

Here is a sample code of what I tried.

**server.py** :

```
from bottle import route, run,request
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
import time

valur = 0

@route('/hello/<name>', method = 'GET')
def index(name):
    print valur
    time.sleep(9)
    return str(valur)

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, reloader =False,interval=10, server='gevent')
```

Comment: just use stunnel and you're done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I found a simple solution for this problem after series of
  exploration.
- By just adding the `private key` and `certificate file` location in the
  server we can enable TLS\SSL support to your server.

The modified sorce code is given below,

```
run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, reloader =False,interval=10, server='gevent', certfile='server.crt', keyfile='server.key')
```